# Correlation value not capturing in loadrunner

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I am doing correlation for my application, also I have placed it in the proper place, boundaries are correct, included web set, max. But I am still getting this error

> Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter
>   "c_datatable". Either the specified boundaries were not found in the
>   response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter
>   size of 99999 bytes

Comment: It is impossible to advise until you share more information. Please add a sample response with correlated value and the corresponding piece of code.

Comment: "LB/IC=<html>","RB/IC=</html>","ORD=1",LAST)   this would be backing out to the ultimate extreme, but then you could use any string parsing code you wanted to get to the value you need.